# add relation on non primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a269d/2)

How I show report in repeater speciality wise

```
DERMATOLOGIST  
ABC  ABC  Female  2014-01-01  
4    4      Male  


SELECT Patient_Name,Visit_Date,Speciality,PATIENT_VISIT.REF_PHY_ID,REF_PHY_MASTER.NAME 
FROM PATIENT_VISIT
LEFT JOIN REF_PHY_MASTER
ON PATIENT_VISIT.REF_PHY_ID = REF_PHY_MASTER.REF_PHY_ID
INNER JOIN PATIENT_MASTER ON PATIENT_MASTER.PID = PATIENT_VISIT.PID
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Visit_Date, 101) AS DATETIME)='2014-01-25'
```

I have taken an reference of this link

[ref link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/11/02/parent-child-datatable-nested-repeaters.aspx)

Comment: Hamlet i have to show report in repeater Speciality wise which is the column of REF_PHY_MASTER which is repeating in table so how can i add relation between parent table and child table e=reference link http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/11/02/parent-child-datatable-nested-repeaters.aspx

Comment: For physican speciality how many patient visited